# Can a transaction in org1 peer1 be queried from org2 peer1?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a smart contract in ORG1.MSP peer1 and I'll like to query it from ORG2.MSP peer1. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If they're both on the same channel, they have access to the same ledger, which contains blocks, which contain transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the ChainCode on each peer which should make use of its functions. If you want them to work on the same ledger, let the peers join the same channel, install the chaincode on them and then you are able to execute transactions via chaincode on the ledger(s).

So **yes** it is possible.